# How can I obtain the correct user agent header on Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, user-agent

My web API captures the requesting client's User-Agent header for analytics purposes. When run in local IIS, everything is fine

```
Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString()
```

gets me the user agent string.

However, when deployed to Azure, I get "EMA-Gateway" as the user agent string, defeating my analytics. I assume this is because there is a load-balancing proxy in front of my API. My question is: can I recover the requester's user agent  string when running in Azure, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a WebAPI hosted in an Azure Web App (WebSite) and it correctly discerns the user agent.  Could the "EMA Gateway" be injected by an intermediary, like a proxy, between you and Azure?

Comment: I have deployed as an "API App", not a web app. I am beginning to think I should have deployed as a web app.

Comment: I have re-deployed as a Web App, and can get the correct user agent header. I should probably have done this in the first place. It seems that "API App" puts the app behind some sort of proxy which obscures information about the requesting client. Thanks for the help!